# SQL remove row with same values on limited values in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried several threads without finding an answer. 
If you have two columns, how do I remove line 2 and 4 with same value from my query, please? I cannot simply use ID1<>ID2 because it concern only some numbers (let`s say 11,13)

```
 ID1 ID2
 10  43
 11  11
 12  45
 13  13
```

Comment: What about the 3rd record? Your question title and the description is contradicting..

Comment: 3rd record I need it

Comment: Well.. Then you can go on with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

selecting rows where ids are equal

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE ID1 = ID2;
```

selecting rows where ids are not equal

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE ID1 != ID2;
```

And for deleting the records, replace `SELECT *` to `DELETE`.

Comment: I am not righting on the database but just consulting it

Comment: Do you want to delete the data where id1=id2 or select? Also you just updated to question to id not equals to id2 without updating title.

Comment: i want to delete from a select statement

Comment: @MafPipo . . . If this solves your problem, you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID1<>ID2;` should do what you are looking for, if I got your problem correctly.

Here, `<>` is `NOT EQUAL`. Sometime it is also written as `!=`, depending on the DBMS.